# Which card has the highest number of mana symbols in its mana cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Color doesn't matter. No Un-Sets. In case of a tie, one card tied for highest number suffices. I need such a card as a test case for a computer program involving MtG cards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus) has 10.  This is easy to check in gatherer, just use [CMC >= 10](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&cmc=%20%3E=%5B10%5D), and see that it's the max.

[Draco](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Draco) has the largest generic mana number, at 16.  (Observed using the same query.)

If you include unsets (I know you didn't want that, but for completeness, and because I love them) [Big Furry Monster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Big%20Furry%20Monster) from Unglued has 15. And [Gleemax](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleemax) has generic mana requirement of 1,000,000.

Comment: Don't really care about un-sets because I'm not going to implement them anyway.

Comment: Still interesting to include them in the answer for completeness.

Comment: There's no maximum generic cost; a card with X in its cost can cost as much as the player chooses. Furthermore, there are ways that a card can cost more than its CMC: other cards can make it cost more, there can be a kicker cost, etc.

Comment: Also, your BFM link doesn't work. It's http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9780

Comment: And we're unlikely to ever see a card with more than Progenitus, because a) 11+ cost cards are few and far between, b) it's hard to read that many mana symbols, for very little gain, and c) you start to run out of space to put the card's name.  There's a reason Progenitus doesn't have a title.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I don't know, I mean "Our Market Research Shows That Players Like Really Long Card Names So We Made this Card to Have the Absolute Longest Card Name Ever Elemental" exists after all XD Really I think the reason there won't be anything with more than Prog is how oppressive it is to have to spend that much specific mana, 2 of each is a big ask as it is, add in any more, or many more but of less colors it gets really hard to play (outside possibly mono cards in a mono deck)

Answer (score -2):

Beyond the facial answer of [Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus), with 10 total mana symbols in the mana cost, there are cards that may complicate your programing.

Consider the [Reaper King](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reaper%20King) or [Nobilis of War](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nobilis%20of%20War). Each has 5 hybrid symbols in the casting cost.